# Avoid shrinking/removing wearable micro app from apk file

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, shrinkresources

I activated the resouce shrinking in my build.gradle but now my embeded wearable app is stripped out. How can I avoid that my micro app is removed, because it is *unused*?

> Skipped unused resource res/raw/android_wear_micro_apk.apk: 382310 bytes

Since I want to shrink the other not used resouces I'm using this DSL:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would guess that I need to use proguard but I have no idea how to achieve that. I checked of cause the documentation, but I didn't get it how protect a single member variable.

Comment: This is probably a bug. You might file an issue at http://b.android.com. Or, if you don't have many other raw resources, try keeping your entire `R.raw` class.

Comment: I would assume that something like `-keep class your.package.name.here.R.raw.** { *; }` would work in your ProGuard configuration file. Note that this would be your actual `package` value from the manifest for whatever package has this raw resource. Given [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78617) I am skeptical that my suggestion will work, but it is at least worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Bug [78620](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78620) and was fixed in the gradle build tools 0.14.1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referencing the `R.raw.apkpath`? Looking at the [Packaging Wearable Apps training](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) mentions `rawPathResId` in the `res/xml/wearable_app_desc.xml`

On a side note enabling proGuard is simple with Gradle

```
 buildTypes {

        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
```

Comment: At first `runProguard` is deprecated. Secondly I was looking for a proguard rule and not how to enabled it in general.